# Script keep showing "SettingCopyWithWarning'

Tags: python, pandas, flask

Hello my problem is that my script keep showing below message

---

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  downcast=downcast

---

I Searched the google for a while regarding this, and it seems like my code is somehow 
assigning sliced dataframe to new variable, which is problematic.

The problem is ** I can't find where my code get problematic **
I tried copy function, or seperated the nested functions, but it is not working

I attached my code below.

```
def case_sorting(file_get, col_get, methods_get, operator_get, value_get):

ops = {">": gt, "<": lt}
col_get = str(col_get)
value_get = int(value_get)

if methods_get is "|x|":
    new_file = file_get[ops[operator_get](file_get[col_get], value_get)]
else:
    new_file = file_get[ops[operator_get](file_get[col_get], np.percentile(file_get[col_get], value_get))]
return new_file
```

Basically what i was about to do was to make flask api that gets excel file as an input, and returns the csv file with some filtering. So I defined some functions first.

```
def get_brandlist(df_input, brand_input):
if brand_input == "default":
    final_list = (pd.unique(df_input["브랜드"])).tolist()
else:
    final_list = brand_input.split("/")
if '브랜드' in final_list:
    final_list.remove('브랜드')
final_list = [x for x in final_list if str(x) != 'nan']
return final_list
```

Then I defined the main function

```
def select_bestitem(df_data, brand_name, col_name, methods, operator, value):

# // 2-1 // to remove unnecessary rows and columns with na values
df_data = df_data.dropna(axis=0 & 1, how='all')
df_data.fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)

# // 2-2 // iterate over all rows to find which row contains brand value
default_number = 0
for row in df_data.itertuples():
    if '브랜드' in row:
        df_data.columns = df_data.iloc[default_number, :]
        break
    else:
        default_number = default_number + 1

# // 2-3 // create the list contains all the target brand names
brand_list = get_brandlist(df_input=df_data, brand_input=brand_name)

# // 2-4 // subset the target brand into another dataframe
df_data_refined = df_data[df_data.iloc[:, 1].isin(brand_list)]

# // 2-5 // split the dataframe based on the "brand name", and apply the input condition
df_per_brand = {}
df_per_brand_modified = {}
for brand_each in brand_list:
    df_per_brand[brand_each] = df_data_refined[df_data_refined['브랜드'] == brand_each]
    file = df_per_brand[brand_each].copy()
    df_per_brand_modified[brand_each] = case_sorting(file_get=file, col_get=col_name, methods_get=methods,
                                                     operator_get=operator, value_get=value)

# // 2-6 // merge all the remaining dataframe
df_merged = pd.DataFrame()
for brand_each in brand_list:
    df_merged = df_merged.append(df_per_brand_modified[brand_each], ignore_index=True)
final_df = df_merged.to_csv(index=False, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
return final_df
```

And I am gonna import this function in my app.py later

I am quite new to all the coding, therefore really really sorry if my code is quite hard to understand, but I just really wanted to get rid of this annoying warning message. Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: I accidentally found the answer, it was dropna that was causing a trouble, so I added .copy to it and it is solved!